# joint density of two relevant random variables

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

It seems that for most of the examples to derive the joint density of two or more random variables, the random variables themselves need to be independent. Is it possible to get the joint density of two relevant random variables?

For example, if
$$dS_t = (r-q)S_tdt + \sigma S_t dB_t$$
and
$$G_t = \frac{1}{t-s} \int_s^t \ln S_u du, \quad t>s>0$$

Then, can I get the joint density of $(S_t, G_t)$ from time $s$ to time $t$?

Some information that may be help:

It is not hard to know that both $S_t$ and $G_t$ subject to normal distribution which may use in deriving their joint distribution.

BTW, whether it is possible to get the distribution of $P(G_t|S_t)$? Then by the formula $P(AB) = P(A|B) \cdot P(B)$, we can get what we want.

Answer (score 1):

Since the solution is a Geometric Brownian motion, you are really studying the joint density of Brownian motion and its integral $(B_t,\int^{t}B_{r})$ (to get the one you mentioned you need to some change of variables and shifts). This has been studied already   eg. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176787/joint-distribution-of-brownian-motion-and-its-time-integral

> Since the Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Gaussian process, the random vector $(W_{t_1},\ldots,W_{t_n})$ is Gaussian for any $t_1,\ldots,t_n \geq 0$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies that the vector

$$X_n := \bigg( W_t, \sum_{j=1}^n W_{t_j} (t_j-t_{j-1}) \bigg)$$

> is Gaussian for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $t>0$ where $t_j:= \frac{j}{n} t$. As $X_n$ converges pointwise to $(W(t),\int_0^t W(s) \, ds)$, we find that the latter is Gaussian as a pointwise limit of Gaussian random variables. Since Gaussian random vectors are uniquely determined by their mean vector and covariance matrix, it just remains to calculate $\mathbb{E}(W_t^2)$, $\mathbb{E}(I_t W_t)$, $\mathbb{E}(I_t^2)$ and to note that the mean vector equals $0$.

Comment: if $W_t$ and $\int_0^t W(s) ds$ are subject to normal distribution respectively, why the joint distribution $(W_t, \int_0^t W(s) ds)$ is normal distribution too?

Comment: For each n, the discretization $X_{n}$ is a joint Gaussian since sum of Gaussian is a Gaussian and their joint covariance involves the covariance of Brownian motion.

Comment: Then for the limit, we can use that their means and covariances converge to that of the continuous integral https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144825/limit-of-gaussian-random-variables-is-gaussian.

Comment: sorry for asking again, I mean why "For each n, the discretization $X_n$
 is a joint Gaussian"?  If two stochastic processes are Gaussian, then it seems that their joint distribution is not always Gaussian.

Comment: yes, but for the particular definition of Brownian motion is that all joint distributions are Gaussian.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer. Is there any recommended reference introduce about Gaussian process systematically? (including what you said for example, the limit of Gaussian is still Gaussian, the combination of Gaussian is still Gaussian, etc.) I want to master it better. Now, I even don't know why Brownian motion is a Gaussian.

Comment: The above convergence result falls under the general Levy continuity theorem, which you can find in any introductory probability book such as the one by Durrett. Gaussians are usually covered in introductory probability books.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks in advance for one more question. "Since the Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Gaussian process, the random vector $(W_{t_1}, \cdots , W_{t_n})$ is Gaussian for any $t_1, \cdots , t_n≥0 , n \in \mathbb{N}$. " I am confused about the definition of Gaussian. Don't them need to be independent? It is obviously that $(W_{t_1}, \cdots , W_{t_n})$ are not independent from each other.

Comment: Yes, they are dependent i.e. $E[W_{t}W_{s}]=min(t,s)$, and so they define a joint Gaussian distribution with off-diagonal entries given by the correlations. A good book on Brownian motion is the Morters-Peres book.